# inserting time values into databases

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

I'm not sure why I get this error when I test this function. Can anyone please help me fix this?

time_file.readlines()
builtins.ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

I want to create a table for the time and insert all the values listed below, like idx, date, start, end, duration into the table.

```
def create_time_table(db, time_file):
    '''Time Table should be ID,Date,Start,End,Duration
    '''

    con = sqlite3.connect(db)
    cur = con. cursor()

    cur.execute('''DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Time''')

    # create the table
    cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE TIME(idTEXT, DateTEXT, StartTEXT, EndTEXT,
    DurationTEXT)''')


    # insert the rows
    time_file.readlines()
    for line in time_file:
        data = line.split(',')
        idx = data[0]
        date = data[1]
        start = data[2]
        end = data[3]
        duration = data[4]
        cur.execute('''INSERT INTO TIME VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)''',(idx, date, start, end, duration))
  if __name__ == '__main__':
 file2 = open('time.csv', 'r')
create_time_table("exams.db", file2)
file2.close()
```

Comment: That means the file was closed before you passed it into `create_time_table()`.

Comment: So do I need to open it right before reading it?

Comment: Not necessarily. You just need to make sure it's not closed when you try to read it. Can you add the code that calls `create_time_table()`...

Comment: Check my edit. I have to close the file though afterwards.

Comment: You should use `with open('time.csv') as f: create_time_table('exams.db', f)` [[docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)]. And you don't want to call `time_file.readlines()` because that will consume all the lines in the file without doing anything with them.

Comment: shouldn't it be f = open('time.csv', 'r')?

Comment: No, it shouldn’t be. See the docs.

Comment: Do I do that in the shell?

Answer (score 0):

@bigd since we are in the same class lol... here is the solution.. Your mistake is how you are reading the file, it should be time_file.readline(), if you do time_file.readlines(), using sqliteonline, the table would not appear.

```
def create_time_table(db, time_file):
'''Time Table should be ID,Date,Start,End,Duration
'''

con = sqlite3.connect(db)
cur = con. cursor()

cur.execute('''DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Time''')

# create the table
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE Time(ID TEXT, Date TEXT, Start TEXT, End TEXT,
DurationTEXT)''')


# insert the rows
clock_file = open(time_file, 'r')
clock_file.readline()
for line in clock_file:
    data = line.strip().split(',')
    idx = data[0]
    date = data[1]
    start = data[2]
    end = data[3]
    duration = data[4]
    cur.execute('''INSERT INTO TIME VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)''',(idx, date, start, end, duration))

 # commit and close the cursor and connection
con.commit()
cur.close()
con.close()    


## Under if __name__ == '__main__': ##
create_time_table('exams.db', 'time.csv')
```

Comment: DOn't we have to open the file as well in if main?

Comment: time_file2 = open(time_file, 'r')
builtins.TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper
I get this error now.

Comment: No, we do not have to open it in the main. Only thing the main should have is  db = 'exams.db' and functions names like create_location_table(). Copy and paste the code, it should work

Comment: BUt it says open and close the file in the comments

Comment: The file is already closed from this con.commit()
cur.close()
con.close()

Comment: Those comments are for us to do within the sql coding by doing CREATE TABLE, then  insert Rows, then INSERT Values and then close the cursor with the given function

Comment: So what are the comments in if main for? It kinda repeats what we did in the function.

Comment: So we can ignore the comments where it says open and close the file under if main?

Comment: For main, all there should be is db = 'exams.db'. So all your tables will be in the exams database. For now, try this and see if it works and then ask the prof on piazza. I would chat with you via stackoverflow but do not have many points to do so lol

Comment: It works now when I test it. I have a question about the locations table btw, I get everything after Id 1 when I test it, but I can't get Id 1 for some reason. How do I go about that?

Comment: How did you read your csv file? If you do it the same way, as this one, it should work fine unless you did not download the new csv file update. Try downloading the csv file again and it should work

Comment: I edited your code to remove whitespace and /n in your output. Have you figured out get_instructors function yet lol?

Comment: I have no idea how to do that. I followed everyhting and it still doesn't work.